# What corresponds to a Zoom value of false in Aspose Cells?

Tags: zooming, excel-interop, aspose, aspose-cells, page-setup

I'm refactoring some Excel Interop code to utilize Aspose Cells. One of the legacy lines of code related to printing a sheet is:

```
xlSheet.PageSetup.Zoom = false;
```

Aspose Cells does have a [Sheet].PageSetup.Zoom property, but it is an int, not a bool.

What corresponds to false - 100?

### UPDATE

In response to the answer, the legacy (Excel Interop) code is:

```
xlSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1;
xlSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 10;
xlSheet.PageSetup.Zoom = false;
```

So, the original developer was setting the zoom vals and then saying disregard them? Or am I to understand that setting zoom to false *does* coincide with setting those values, and as long as I set the FitToPages* properties in Aspose, setting PageSetup.Zoom to false is moot/redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note, in Excel Interop the PageSetup.Zoom = false means no zoom has to be applied to the worksheet, and the FitToPagesWide and FitToPagesTall properties control how the worksheet is scaled. If you wish to achieve the same with Aspose.Cells APIs, please set the PageSetup.FitToPagesTall & FitToPagesWide according to the application requirements. Aspose.Cells will automatically ignore any preferences set for Worksheet's zoom.

*Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.*